# PHP cURL: Read a specific response header

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I am using cURL in PHP to POST to an endpoint that is creating a resource. It returns a 201 response with a Location header giving the URL of the resource created. I also get some information in the body of the response.

What's the best way to get the plain-text body of the response, and also get the value of the location header? curl_getinfo doesn't return that header, and when I do this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($ch, $header) {
        var_dump($header);
    });
```

I only see one header dumped out--the "HTTP/1.1 201 Created" response code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);

// Print header
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr)
    printf('<p>Header: %s</p>', $hdr);

// Print Content
echo $content;
```

Comment: What if `\r\n\r\n` appears in the body?

Comment: This has a few possible pitfalls if used on the wider internet: some servers will not use /r/n line endings, sometimes your request will be in response to a 100-continue request and have multiple header sections etc

Comment: Even thought this works, it should be considered vulnerable!